# How do I solve this android studio error?

Tags: javascript, angular, flutter, dart

I'm trying to start android studio through wsl on windows 10 and I am getting this error

```
Start Failed
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createToolkit(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:40)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:599)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1498)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1104)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1493)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:473)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:330)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:607)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1558)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1368)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1315)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:125)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:105)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:167)
        at com.intellij.ide.ui.html.GlobalStyleSheetHolder.<clinit>(GlobalStyleSheetHolder.kt:34)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$preloadLafClasses$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:523)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '172.28.208.1:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
                at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
                at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:107)
                at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
                at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
                at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:36)
                at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
                at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:88)
                at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:116)
                at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:514)
                at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createToolkit(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:40)
                at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:599)
                at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$initAwtToolkit$1$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:424)
                at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '172.28.208.1:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. [in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-5"]
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:107)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:36)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:88)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:116)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:514)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createToolkit(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:40)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:599)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$initAwtToolkit$1$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:424)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        ... 4 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/home/odongo/android-studio/jbr

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createToolkit(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:40)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:599)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.<init>(EventQueue.java:264)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.initEQ(SunToolkit.java:177)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.createNewAppContext(SunToolkit.java:316)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:273)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:262)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:262)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:315)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:298)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:297)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<init>(Component.java:1023)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.<init>(Container.java:300)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.<init>(JComponent.java:641)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:317)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:254)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(JTextPane.java:100)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupErrorReporter.showMessage(StartupErrorReporter.java:85)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupErrorReporter.showMessage(StartupErrorReporter.java:39)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.kt:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '172.28.208.1:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. [in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-5"]
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:107)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:36)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:88)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:116)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:514)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createToolkit(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:40)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:599)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$initAwtToolkit$1$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:424)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

I was trying to start android studio

Comment: Did you checked this answer? :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53599628/19807154